# Relative Date filter (IsInPreviousNMonths) is not refreshed

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am using the following query (when connecting to SQL database in Direct Query mode) to get appointments for the previous 12 months:

```
Table.SelectRows(dbo_ReportAppointmentsView, each Date.IsInPreviousNMonths([Date], 12))
```

It was working perfectly fine and was generating SQL query with where clause like:

```
where convert(date, [_].[Date]) >= convert(datetime2, '2015-11-01 00:00:00') and convert(date, [_].[Date]) < convert(datetime2, '2016-11-01 00:00:00'))
```

The problem is that when current month changed (November -> December) it is still generating SQL query with exactly the same dates.
I expected the dates be '2015-12-01' and '2016-12-01' to display data for previous 12 months.

It helps to press "Refresh" button in Power BI desktop but it is clearly not a maintainable solution if I want the report to automatically display correct data.
 
Is it a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour appeared to be a [known issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34ec0be4-bd22-41a8-bb05-b185254e8e60/relative-date-filter-isinpreviousnmonths-is-not-refreshed?forum=powerquery#97fbaba2-d495-47f2-8d79-fca9857e3ae0).

> The behavior you're observing when using Direct Query against SQL is a
>   known issue with the legacy Direct Query architecture. We will be
>   moving SQL Direct Query to a new architecture over the next few
>   months, but until then there's unfortunately no workaround besides
>   manually refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

If by saying "Direct Query mode" you mean "Native Query", then it is not best practice and should be avoided.

Other than that, try replacing `Date.IsInPreviousNMonths` with something like

```
LocalDT = Date.LocalNow() //May be replaces with desired #date(2016, 11, 25) and likewise
ThisMonthStart = #date(Date.Year(LocalDT), Date.Month(LocalDT), 1),
CompareDate = Date.AddMonths(ThisMonthStart, -12),
Table.SelectRows(dbo_ReportAppointmentsView, each [Date] >= CompareDate)
```

and see if it generates another dates in query.

If you indeed using Native Query, then perhaps this is a bug linked to this mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Native Query" means. There are 2 ways to connect to SQL server data source in Power BI desktop: Import and DirectQuery. I use the DirectQuery (also can be called as "live connection") connection which allows to display up to date data in Power BI desktop.

Comment: For simplicity I also tried to use filter: `Table.SelectRows(dbo_ReportAppointmentsView, each [Date] >= DateTime.LocalNow())`. It calculates the time of report creation/deployment and is not changing with later report renders.

Comment: @SergeyYerdekov If so, this is definately a bug. I use PowerQuery, not Power BI, so I installed PBI and checked. Direct query <> Native query. The last is when you supply direct query to Sql.Database finction.
Just note the difference between `DateTime.LocalNow()` and `DateTime.FixedLocalNow()`. The behavior you describe is a proper behavior of `DateTime.FixedLocalNow()`, but not `DateTime.LocalNow()`.

Answer (score 0):

All functions that check for a date(time) in a certain period relative to the system date(time), should be interpreted as ".... at last refresh".

In my opinion this is expected behavior, even when running is Direct Query mode: the latest data is accessed with the query definitions at last refresh.

My suggestion would be create a field in your SQL database with the current system date(time) (or just use it if it is already available) and select your data based on the value from that field.

Comment: That's my current workaround (using GETDATE() function inside SQL view). It has some negative performance consequences but will work for now. As for DateTime.LocalNow() - it should be refreshed at the time of query execution: [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d5ee632-fdff-4ba2-b150-bb3591f955fb/queries-evaluation-chain?forum=powerquery#4d960556-280f-4ac4-82ba-29e7c50a259c)

Comment: Just a wild guess: another workaround might be a scheduled refresh at the start of each month (in this example).
Maybe you should raise an idea for the refresh at the time of query execution (I couldn't find any idea for this).

Comment: This question is cross posted on Technet:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34ec0be4-bd22-41a8-bb05-b185254e8e60/relative-date-filter-isinpreviousnmonths-is-not-refreshed?forum=powerquery